# Jenkins install error

Tags: jenkins

- I'm install jenkins on Window 8.

  - But it is error. I using command line `Java –jar Jenkins.war`
  - This is error

[image]

Thanks all,

Comment: What directory is jenkins.war in? What directory are you in?

Comment: @PaulHicks I copyed it into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\jenkins.war

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your copy, or your download, or something. There's nothing wrong with java or Jenkins (in general). Your war might not have a manifest in it, but the one downloaded from jenkins-ci does. Try downloading it again. (Also try not running it from java's bin directory.)

Comment: @PaulHicks thanks so much. I'm installed jenkins success.